# HTML Dom elements as marker / feature in Openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, markers

I want to set HTML Dom element as marker in openlayers, instead of GIFs,PNGs. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of DOM element would you like to use as a marker?

If you just want to create a simple vector graphic for your marker I recommend to create a symbol like so:

OpenLayers.Renderer.symbol.BN = [0,9, 3,4.5, 8.5,4.5, 4.5,0, 8.5,-4.5, 3,-4.5, 0,-9, -3,-4.5, -8.5,-4.5, -4.5,0, -8.5,4.5, -3,4.5, 0,9];

Answer (score 1):

```
var marker = new ol.Overlay({
    position: pos,
    positioning: 'center-center',
    element: document.getElementById('marker'),
    stopEvent: false
});
```

Here `marker` is div: `<div id="marker" title="Marker"></div>`

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the Tour, which explains how our "Focused question / Best answer" model works. Your answer should be long enough that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a short answer; without any explanation. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed or downvoted

Answer (score 0):

You can pass external graphic with parameter in OpenLayers Vector, for example:

```
vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
                "Move feature",
                {
                    // The zIndex is taken from the zIndex attribute of the features
                    styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                        externalGraphic: "img/marker-google.png",
                        pointRadius: 20
                    }),
                    isBaseLayer: false
                }
            );
    map.addLayers([vectorLayer]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to draw HTML on map as feature, say showing vehicle on map and vehicle icon will be some <div> etc, but not .png, .gif